# Changing an array of objects structure in Javascript for Sencha Touch Ext.ux.TouchCalendar

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm building a Sencha Touch app that utilizes the awesome calendar plugin https://github.com/SwarmOnline/Ext.ux.TouchCalendar , however, some custom implementation is needed in order to utilize the events functionality.

I've already tied the events template to a store, which fetches data from the server. It works as planned, but the problem is the plugin looks for ALL records in the store and counts each one as an event (because in the event model, it looks for "date" as the start and end point). So every day looks like has an event, even though those without "items" are blank, see: http://cl.ly/image/3j461O2L2Y1k. I only want to display events with "items"

My data from the server that comes back in the following format (many days do not have "items"):

```
 [
  {
  "day":28,
  "iscurrentmonth":false,
  "issunday":false,
  "date":"2013-05-28",

  "items":[
     {
        "id":134513,
        "title":"Subject",
        "typeid":3,
        "typename":"Essay",
        "author":"Bryan Fisher",
        "classname":"English 9A",
        "classid":344499,
        "courseid":60555
     },
     {
        "id":134485,
        "title":"Subject",
        "typeid":3,
        "typename":"Essay",
        "author":"Bryan Fisher",
        "classname":"English 10",
        "classid":344500,
        "courseid":60555
     }
  ]
 }
]
```

So, I have to change the data array's structure into the following format:

```
[
  {
  "date":"2013-05-28",
  "id":134513,
  "title":"Subject",
  "typeid":3,
  "typename":"Essay",
  "author":"Bryan Fisher",
  "classname":"English 9A",
  "classid":344499
 },
 {
  "date":"2013-05-28",
  "id":134485,
  "title":"Subject",
  "typeid":3,
  "typename":"Essay",
  "author":"Bryan Fisher",
  "classname":"English 10",
  "classid":344500
 }
]
```

How can I change the original object to match the new format? (take the "date" and insert it into the "items" node) ?

I am completely open to something like underscore.js

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I over thought this whole thing...

A bit of a hack...

in TouchCalendarEvents.js I added the following method to check for an empty event div

```
hideOthers: function(){
    var bar = $('.event-bar');

    for (var i = 0; i < bar.length; i++){
        var allBars = bar[i];
        if (allBars.innerHTML == ''){
            console.log('number ' + i + 'is Empty!' );

            allBars.remove();

        }
    }
},
```

and call it in refreshEvents

```
refreshEvents: function(){

    // scroll the parent calendar to the top so we're calculating positions from the base line.
    if(this.calendar.getScrollable()){
        this.calendar.getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(0,0);
    }

    this.removeEvents();

    this.getViewModeProcessor().generateEventBars(); // in turn calls this.renderEventBars(this.eventBarStore);

    this.createEventWrapper();

    this.hideOthers();


    if (this.getAllowEventDragAndDrop()) {
        this.createDroppableRegion();
    }
},
```

Works well enough for now!